# Scrape and convert website into HTML?

Tags: html, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I haven't done this in 3 or 4 years, but a client wants to downgrade their dynamic website into static HTML.

Are there any free tools out there to crawl a domain and generate working HTML files to make this quick and painless?

Edit: it is a Coldfusion website, if that matters.

Comment: Problem is they aren't paying to have this done, so, whatever the quickest way without writing code / ssh'ing anything so I can have this done while working on paid work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Getleft](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getleftdown/) is a nice Windows client that can do this. It is very configurable and reliable.

[Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) can, too, with the `--mirror` option.

Answer (score 9):

Try using `httrack` (or `webhttrack`/`winhttrack`, if you want a GUI) to spider the web site.  It's free, fast, and reliable.  It's also much more powerful than primitive downloaders like `wget`; `httrack` is designed for mirroring web sites.

Be aware that converting a dynamic page to static will lose you a lot of functionality.  It's also not always *possible* - a dynamic site can present an infinite number of different static pages.

Comment: I wouldn't call `wget` primitive.

Comment: @strager: Ok then, "relatively primitive".  It's got a much more restricted feature-set when it comes to mirroring sites.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it can do everything httrack does, but don't underestimate `wget --mirror`! It can do a *lot* of things.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I used it, but [webzip](http://www.spidersoft.com/webzip/default.asp) was quite good.

It is not free, but for $35.00, I think your client won't go broke.

A quick google for offline browsers came up with [this](http://www.spadixbd.com/backstreet/) and [this](http://www.httrack.com/) that look good..